# Trouble Installing pip and pandas_ml (Windows, Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble using pip and I'll just head right into explaining the issue. This looks like a lot of text but the majority is just error messages! Thanks sooo much in advance, I need it for a class.

I'm working in Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook (not the subject of the issue, but worth noting), and I entered the following line and got the resulting error message:

```
from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_ml'
```

I then downloaded pip. I noticed I had it on my computer previously, but it didn't seem to work in command line. I also attached the path to my Python36-32/Scripts to my file path in windows environmental variables. I successfully downloaded pip to version 18.1. (Note, I had to use py when installing pip). Now, when running "pip install pandas_ml" in command line (and in Jupyter Notebook), I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas_ml in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.17.0 in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pandas_ml) Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pandas_ml) Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0
>   in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pandas>=0.17.0->pandas_ml) Requirement already satisfied:
>   pytz>=2011k in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pandas>=0.17.0->pandas_ml) Requirement already satisfied:
>   numpy>=1.9.0 in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from pandas>=0.17.0->pandas_ml) Requirement already satisfied:
>   six>=1.5 in
>   c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
>   (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas>=0.17.0->pandas_ml) You are using
>   pip version 9.0.3, however version 18.1 is available. You should
>   consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'
>   command.

Notice that it says I'm on version 9.0.3 despite when installing pip, it says I'm on version 18.1. Then, when I go to do the update it suggests, I get the following error message:

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Remember, I had to use "py" instead of python at first. I try "py -m pip install --upgrade pip" and I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip__main__.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa   File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_internal__init__.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor'

I also noticed I have Python36 and Python36-32 (I added both to Path to see if it would affect anything, it didn't). I don't know if that's an issue or not. Is it possible my pip is linked to the wrong Python or something (I don't know how this works).

So, despite all this work, I still cannot import anything from pandas_ml on Jupyter notebook. Interestingly, I did manage to successfully "from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix" in eclipse. However, there I can't seem to import other packages such as scikitlearn and matplotlib. (Eclipse uses "....\Python36-32\Python.exe".

Thanks again to everyone who helps, it'll be VERY appreciated!

EDIT: Just had the thought that since pandas_ml is installed on my computer, the issue might be that the folder designated for Jupyter Notebook does not contain the file for it. Is it possible to copy it there without any consequences?

Comment: I'd suggest just uninstalling all the existing Python and libraries and starting again from scratch, as it sounds like you have two versions mixed together.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the same thing. How would that affect my anaconda/jupyter notebook and eclipse applications?

Comment: Do you use virtual environments? I'd highly recommend to avoid any installation conflicts. That's what they're for after all! Conda has great documentation on this: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html